# How do I get text that someone has entered into a text field and input this into my SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

So, I'm creating the log in activity for my new app. If a user is signing up, I will need to store the info that they enter into the sign up form to be stored inside of my SQLite database. How do I go about doing this? This is what I have so far:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "USERS";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE DATABASE USERS("
                + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + "USERNAME TEXT, "
                + "EMAIL_ADDRESS TEXT, "
                + "PASSWORD TEXT); ");
        insertUser(db, "");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    private static void insertUser (SQLiteDatabase db, String username, String email, String password){
        ContentValues userValues = new ContentValues();
        userValues.put("USERNAME", username);
        userValues.put("EMAIL_ADDRESS", email);
        userValues.put("PASSWORD", password);
        db.insert("USERS", null, userValues);
    };
}
```

Comment: In signing up class, you have to call insertUser method.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad, but in any case do not store your users' passwords as clear text in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You have make a query to fetch the records from SQLite database.

Here is a simple example to fetch all users:

```
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = db.query("USERS", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            User user = new User();
            user.setUsername(cursor.getString(1));
            user.setEmail(cursor.getString(2));
            users.add(user);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return users;
}
```

You can read more about it in the following link:

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/